# jquery Tags not generated by $.post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

on my Page I'm loading the table-content on an asynchronous way:

```
$.post( "test.php", function( data ) {
     $('#myTableBody').html(data);
     //refresh the content by jQuery 
});
```

into the following table-body:

```
<table>
 <thead>
   ...
 </thead>
 <tbody id='myTableBody'>
   <!--No Content before loading it -->
 </tbody>
</table>
```

The `test.php` contains the table-body-content in normal table-format, like `<tr><td></td></tr>`, with `jQuery`- and `Twitter-Bootstrap`-Tags for pop-up's or dialogs. (The Code for those tags is not necessary, because I think there should be a way to refresh jQuery by one common tag? )

On a static page-load those `jQuery`-Tags are replaced by the `css` and `html`-Tags defined by jQuery when the `device-ready` event appears.

But now my question is, how to say to `jQuery/ js/ twitter-bootstrap`, that there is new content. How to trigger to re-replace it?

Comment: Is your question how to check if there is new content to load into the table or is it how to make the example you've posted work?

Comment: What's a "jQuery tag"? jQuery is a JavaScript framework. Do you mean a script tag that contains jQuery code that's part of the HTML? Might be useful if we could see what `data` actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready), so that is DOM is ready to manipulate like,

```
jQuery(function($){
    $.post( "test.php", function( data ) {
         $('#myTableBody').html(data);
         //refresh the content by jQuery 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look into long-polling if you want to look for new content to load into your table.

Basically what you do is continuously ask for new content to load into the table by doing multiple AJAX requests after each other with a certain period between, but instead of immediately returning the response from the server you delay the response until it time out or there is new content to send to the client.

Take a look at the example presented here:

http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery

If you want really quick updates you could look into Socket.IO http://socket.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can use .append() function to place new content on page.

In Ajax function:

```
$.post( "test.php", function( data ) {
     $("#myTableBody").append(data);
});
```